# Perforce: How to checkout file same file from different version?

Tags: perforce, vcs-checkout, changelist

For example, I have 100s of files checked out in a changelist:

```
//Development/MyProject/Version1.0/Coord/File1.cs
//Development/MyProject/Version1.0/Coord/File2.cs
...
//Development/MyProject/Version1.0/Coord/Filen.cs
//Development/MyProject/Version1.0/Common/File1.cs
...
//Development/MyProject/Version1.0/Common/Filen.cs
```

Similarly in some more directories. Now I want to checkout similar files in `Version2.0`

```
//Development/MyProject/Version2.0/Coord/File1.cs
//Development/MyProject/Version2.0/Coord/File2.cs
...
//Development/MyProject/Version2.0/Coord/Filen.cs
//Development/MyProject/Version2.0/Common/File1.cs
...
//Development/MyProject/Version2.0/Common/Filen.cs
```

I can do this by looking at what files have been checked out in `Version1.0` and go to each directory in `Version2.0` and checkout those files. This is tedious job.

Any aboveboard way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to check out the _exact_ set of files in Version2.0 that are checked out in the version1.0 tree?

Comment: You can make it significantly less tedious by some simple scripting. Pipe 'p4 opened' | sed 's/Version1.0/Version2.0/' | p4 -x - edit. Or something close to that.

Comment: @Mark yes. I am trying to do the same...

Answer (score 1):

From the linux/Unix/macOS shell, I suggest the following method. It would be significantly different in Windows unless you had unix tools installed there.

1. Check out all your Version1.0 files.
2. cd to your **Version1.0** directory
3. Run the following command line:

`p4 opened ... | sed 's/\#[1-9].*$//' | sed 's/\/Version1.0\//\/Version2.0\//' | 
p4 -x - edit`

Note: this would need some tweaking if any of your files have '#' symbols in their names. It's a quick-and-dirty fix. And credit to Bryan Pendleton above, who basically said the same thing much more briefly.